# How do GIT branches work?

Tags: git, github

I have a query about GIT branches, and the documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

The scenario:

I have an application.
I want to make some edits, so I create a branch on my repository.
I make commits on the branch.

Now, how do I view these edits in a live environment, without committing them to the master live application.

I obviously need to check the edits in a live environment before committing to the main application?

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create some sort of staging environment, maybe on your local machine, maybe on a server in the cloud - it all depends on what kind of environment your "live" environment is. Then you can push your changes to that environment and see how it affects your product before merging your changes back into your master branch.

Comment: Its an MVC installation, php & mysql, so I'll need to figure out how to get this to work in the cloud i suppose

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up staging environment;
2. Push the new branch to staging;
3. See how it goes;
4. Work further or merge/rebase with master and go live.

The issue itself has nothing to do with git branching.

As to

> Worrying thing is that Google doesnt really give much searching for
>   "git staging environment"

Your search keywords are: **php mysql staging environment**

Comment: Worrying thing is that Google doesnt really give much searching for "git staging environment"

Comment: because it has nothing to do with git :)

Comment: I hereby declare this is much more involved than i thought it would be. Is it really worth all the faffing about, i may as well just run a mirror application and scribble down changed areas!

Comment: "Is it really worth all the faffing about" - *yes*.

Comment: I have a mirror version of the live application. I usually develop on the mirror and then when happy transfer changed files to the live environment. This whole trying to learn GIT or some sort of version control is because sometimes I don't write down all the files that have been changed, or because it is a tedious and sometimes erroneous task to remember everything that's changed. From what I read, I thought I could change the files through the GIT repo, test it, and then when happy commit the changes.

Comment: When in fact it seems that I already have a 'Staging enviroment' the only thing I lack is a list of files that have changed

Comment: Learning how to use GIT to this level, including a staging environment is no easy feat

Comment: Why do you need a list of files? Is your project that big that you cannot just copy the whole project when you release?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the *literal* answer to your question

On the live server alter the branch to the new branch you've made and pull the changes

Check it works on the live system

If it is broken, simply revert to the master branch by checking this out again

**This is an incredibly stupid idea** but - under completely different circumstances - companies like netflicks do do something a bit like this.  Look up "Blue-Green Deploys".  They mitigate the problems of broken stuff in live by having many many duplicated failover load balanced copies of their live environment

I'd just like to reemphasis that "trying out stuff" on your live server is dumb